# Existence of a projection in a strongly closed hereditary $C^*$-algebra of a von Neuman algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a  von Neumann algebra and $B$ is a strongly closed hereditary $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$. Prove that, there exists a unique projection $p$ in $B$ such that $B=pAp.$
$\underline{\text{Definition:}}$ A $C^*$-subalgebra $B$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is called **hereditary** if for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ the inequality $0\le a\le b$ implies $a \in B$.

My approach: Since $A$ is von Neumann algebra and $B$ is a strongly closed $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$, then $B$ is also a von Neumann algebra. Assuming $B \neq 0,$ it is unital and let the unit in $B$ be $p$. I think this is the required projection. But how can I show that $pAp=B?$ And what about the uniqueness? I have to use hereditary condition somewhere, but I failed.
Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $a\ge 0$ then $ \|a\|\,p\ge pap\ge 0.$ hence $pap\in B.$ Every element $a\in A$ is a linear combination of $4$ positive elements. Thus $pap\in B,$ i.e. $pAp\subset B.$ Besides $B=pBp\subset pAp .$

Comment: Don’t you need to argue that $B$ Is unital?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you sir. One thing to ask, can you please tell me how to go for uniqueness of $p$? Because if $pAp=qAq$ then how can I get $p=q$?

Comment: @JonathanHole $B$ itself a von Neumann algebra, so its unital.

Comment: If $pAp=qAq$ then $p=qaq$ for some $a\in A.$ Hence $(I-q)p=0$ i.e. $p=qp.$ Similarly $q=p\tilde{a}p$ for some $\tilde{a}\in A,$ thus $q(I-p)=0 $ and $q=qp.$ Actually, like @JonathanHole, I have also doubts about the automatic existence of the unit in $B.$ I guess it is a nontrivial theorem. My line of a proof would be to take a maximal projection in $B$ and show that it is a unit. Besides please do not adress me "sir", just Ryszard.